# Overwrite first column on xlsx

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to overwrite the data of my first column of a given sheet ('Genus') on an Excel file with multiple sheets. The Data comes from a pandas data frame. 
This is the code that I'm using:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

    df = pd.DataFrame(analysis_data)

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Raw.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='w')
    writer.book = load_workbook('Raw.xlsx')
    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Genus', startrow=0, startcol=0, header=False, index=False)
    writer.save()
    writer.close()
```

I already tried changing the mode of ExcelWrite to 'a' instead of 'w', but it always adds a new sheet with the same name ('Genus1'). Any idea how can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You think you should use [Context manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html)
    given a df

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox\Raw.xlsx')

print(df)

   a   b
0  1   7
1  2   8
2  3   9
3  4  10
4  5  44
5  6  11

df.a = [10,20,30,40,50,60]

with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox\Raw.xlsx') as writer:  
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Genus',index=False)


df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox\Raw.xlsx')


print(df)


print(df)
    a   b
0  10   7
1  20   8
2  30   9
3  40  10
4  50  44
5  60  11
```